# How can I get guard for rspec to watch my current directory instead of only /spec

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

When I use

```
bundle exec guard
```

and I change tests in a `spec/` directory they run.

How can I get guard to run tests that are in the current directory (i.e. root) of the project?  Also how can i get guard to watch app files as well?

I see the section with

```
rspec = dsl.rspec
watch(rspec.spec_helper) { rspec.spec_dir }
watch(rspec.spec_support) { rspec.spec_dir }
watch(rspec.spec_files)
```

I tried

```
watch(rspec.spec_files) {'.'}
```

and

```
watch('.')
```

and...

```
#  watch(rspec.spec_files) { rspec.spec_dir + '../' }                                             
#  watch(rspec.spec_files) { './blob/' }
#  watch(rspec.spec_files) {'.'}
#  watch('.')
#  watch(rspec.spec_files) {''}
#  watch(rspec.spec_files) {'.'}
#  watch('*') {'.'}
```

Also app.rb changes aren't picked up.

So how can i watch `thing_spec.rb` or `thing.rb` if either is in the root directory of the project. or in the case of thing.rb, elsewhere in the project, including root.

but neither helped (file still not picked up)

Comment: Can you print out the value of `rspec.spec_dir`?

Comment: Sure how do i do that, i tried a few things but failed

Comment: just `puts "SPEC DIR: #{rspec.spec_dir}`